# Can High CPU be triggered by Login Failures?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance

On our SQL Server (used for TFS) we have recently had the CPU pegged at 100% (with a few occasional dips) for nearly a day and a half.

Looking at the SQL Logs, there appears to be a correlation in time between seeing "Login Failure" errors for a 3rd Party App and the prolonged CPU chewing. The Login Failure errors appeared at about the time yesterday when the problems were reported.

Even a restart of the SQL Server didn't alleviate the problem, it just went back to 100% soon after coming back up.

Myself and one of our DBA's have had a good hard look at the SPID's in SQL and there is nothing obvious or different to any other time.

This box is a little under-provisioned and spends most of its life at about 70-80% CPU.

From the SQL Logs the following messages repeat at about 20-60 second intervals:

```
Date        05/11/2014 11:33:48
Log     SQL Server (Archive #3 - 05/11/2014 12:04:00)

Source      Logon

Message
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows
authentication. [CLIENT: w.x.y.x]
_________________________________________________________________________________________

Date        05/11/2014 11:33:48
Log     SQL Server (Archive #3 - 05/11/2014 12:04:00)

Source      Logon

Message
Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
_________________________________________________________________________________________

Date        05/11/2014 11:33:48
Log     SQL Server (Archive #3 - 05/11/2014 12:04:00)

Source      Logon

Message
SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing a
connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. 
Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. 
The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure.  [CLIENT: w.x.y.x].
_________________________________________________________________________________________

Date        05/11/2014 11:33:48
Log     SQL Server (Archive #3 - 05/11/2014 12:04:00)

Source      Logon

Message
Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.
```

There are also similar Audit Failure errors in the Windows Security Event Log that match the Client IP address and times.

Could something like this cause the last of the CPU to be consumed?

Since logging off all users on the client `w.x.y.z` I have not seen any more login failures and CPU has returned to normal levels.